# UserLogin function in Joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla3.0

Please can anyone tell the new login function used in Joomla 3.5 and above. I found this particular method in previous version of Joomla which fires on login.

```
class PlgUserAddInfo extends JPlugin
{
    public function onUserLogin($user, $options = array())
    {
        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        $mysignum = $user->username;
        $session = JFactory::getSession();
        $session->set('sign', $sign);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose? Are you making your own login system? Are you making an authentication plugin? What is your objective?

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla 2.5 function `onUserLogin()` is used for your purpose. But in latest Joomla version 3.5 function `onUserAfterLogin()` is used.

You can also follow the link https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onUserAfterLogin for more reference.

Comment: On the same page at the top you forgot to see the OnUserLogin function.